# Using while loop with explode in php

Tags: php, while-loop, explode

I explode words and use that words in web page. And also I have some data in mysql database regarding to tat words. I want to be show each word with mysql data.

Explain:

I have those 3 words in database like this audi,opel,toyota

I'm using explode command and separate each word

And then I want to put output of $query to each separated word

audi - %25
opel - %10
toyota - %35

```
function myoptions($aid,$opt){

$query = mysql_query("SELECT oy_secenek, count(*) / (SELECT count(*) FROM anket_oylar) * 100 as yuzde FROM anket_oylar WHERE oy_anket_id = '$aid' GROUP BY oy_secenek");
while ($row= row($query)){
    $yuzde = $row["yuzde"];
    echo '<br />'.$yuzde;
}

$bol = explode(",", $opt);
$seceneks = array();
foreach ($bol as $secenek){


    $secenek = '<br /><input type="radio" name="secenek" id="'.ss(trim($secenek)).'" value="'.ss(trim($secenek)).'" >'.ss(trim($secenek)).' -> '.ss(trim($yuzde));

    array_push($seceneks, $secenek);
}
echo implode("", $seceneks);
}
```

Comment: What kind of SQL dialect is that?

Comment: First I explode line and show that in screen. and also I want to show data regarding to that seperated workds from different table.

Comment: Have your function a return call? your sample code don't have sense, it function doesn't have return and there isn't any call to myoptions

Comment: You didn't answer my question: what the `do()` line should achieve? To me it seems just some broken PHP.

Comment: it is another function to shorten to sql statement. don't think about it

Comment: I think the answer is simple, but you need to share more code than that to get the correct help.

Comment: I changed sql query line.

Comment: What happens if your SQL Query fails? or if it returns 0 Rows? You have nothing to catch that in your function. Also your `foreach()` is outside of the `while`, so you will only get the last value from your recordset.

Comment: Think about this is a poll script and need to put results after options

Comment: Give us an example of `$aid` and `$opt`. It's still making no sense.

Comment: you can take aid = 1 and opt=audi

Comment: `If delimiter is an empty string (""), explode() will return FALSE. If delimiter contains a value that is not contained in string and a negative limit is used, then an empty array will be returned, otherwise an array containing string will be returned.` If you feed your function `myoptions(1, "audi")`, it's going to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you feed your function, it could fail in a lot of ways. If sending 1 & "audi", for example, it would fail at the `explode()`. Take a look:

```
function myoptions($aid,$opt){
    $seceneks = array();
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT oy_secenek, count(*) / (SELECT count(*) FROM anket_oylar) * 100 as yuzde FROM anket_oylar WHERE oy_anket_id = '$aid' GROUP BY oy_secenek");
    while ($row= row($query)){
        $yuzde = $row["yuzde"];
        echo '<br />'.$yuzde;

        if(strpos($opt, ",")){
            $bol = explode(",", $opt);
        } else {
            $bol = array($opt);
        }

        foreach ($bol as $b){
            $seceneks[] = '<br /><input type="radio" name="secenek" id="'.ss(trim($b)).'" value="'.ss(trim($b)).'" >'.ss(trim($b)).' -> '.ss(trim($yuzde));
        }
    }
    if(count($seceneks)){
        echo implode("", $seceneks);
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```